# Check if any checkboxes are checked and if not, display an error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to make a function that checks if any checkboxes generated by this line

```
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item ){
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='productinfo[]' value='" .$item->get_name() . "|" . $item->get_quantity() . "|" . $item->get_total() ."'>";
```

are checked, and if not it displays an error, how do you make one with php/javascript if you can? or do you need jQuery to make one. Preferably if none are checked it would prevent a form submit from being done

Comment: Remember, if a checkbox is Un-Checked it will not be sent to the PHP script.

Comment: I am aware, but I would like to block progression to the next section if none are selected

Comment: jquery is a javascript library, so you can use either of these, its a DOM element you want to check, so php would not be any use in this instance

Comment: So thats easy, if the array is empty (or does not exist) then non are checked

Comment: _Small Note_ jQuery is a javascript framework, not a language in and of itself

Comment: Would it be resolved by using some sort of If-scenario to check if the array is empty? if so could you reciprocate a bit how it would work? also thank you for that jQuery note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick. Check the length of input element with the name productinfo[]" that are checked. In javascript the number `0` is false. All others are true.

The function `console.error()` will log an error to the console. But you can change that to any kind of error message you like.

```js
function checkBoxCheck(e) {
  if ($('input[name="productinfo[]"]:checked').length) {
    console.log("at least one checked");
    return true;
  } else {
    console.error("no checkbox checked");
    return false;
  }
}

$('#myForm').on('submit', checkBoxCheck);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" action="/dummy.html">
  <input type='checkbox' name='productinfo[]' value='1'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='productinfo[]' value='2'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='productinfo[]' value='3'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='productinfo[]' value='4'>

  <input value="Check" type=submit>
</form>
```

Comment: Added an edit request for a fixed version to prevent page submitting even if none are checked

Comment: @Veraen Thanks for the edit. I edited your edit so the function executes on the form `submit` event rather then a button `click` event.

Comment: thanks for editing it so it's a submit instead of a button on-click event this will prove useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `length` of jQuery in order to check atleast one checkbox is checked

```
if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0){
    //your code here
}else{
    alert('Please check atleast one checkbox');
}
```

**Note:** this will check all checkboxes across the page, because your input checkbox has no class.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check if a checkbox is checked use `checked` property in Jquery/Javascript like so:

Jquery:

```
var isChecked =  $('input:checkbox').is(':checked'); // to check if any checkbox is checked 

var isChecked =  $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length; // finds how many checkboxes are checked
if(length > 0){
    alert(length); //alert how many checkboxes are checked
}
```

Javascript:

```
var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    count = 0;

for (var i=0; i<inputElems.length; i++) {       
   if (inputElems[i].type == "checkbox" && inputElems[i].checked == true){
      count++;
   }
}
alert(count)
```

OR you can also use :s

```
var length=document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length
```

Set a `onclick` trigger to a function on the submit button. Change the type of button from `submit` to `button`.

```
<button type ="button" id = "some-id" onclick = "savebutton();">
```

Inside the Javascript function use the validation :

```
 function savebutton(){
    if(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 0){
        alert('None of the checkboxes are checked');
    }else{

        var some_value = document.getElementById('id_of_some_element_you_wish_to_save').value;

        $.ajax({
            url : 'backend.php',
            method : 'POST',
            data: {values_you_want_to_send:some_value}, 
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(data) {
                window.reload();
            }
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
                alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I make it so it checks when I press a form submit button? and if length is 0 it will give an error and make the submit request not go through?

Comment: I will test the update code once I get a chance, hopefully it works @prashant bana

Comment: @Veraen You need a ajax submit? Since I can't find it anywhere in your question.